# why jquery ui tooltip options are not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

on my page I'm trying to apply jquery ui tooltip on a specific element:

```
 <script>
    $(function() {          
           $('.aticker').tooltip(); //works perfectly
    });
</script>
```

but no options are working at all, so:

```
 $('.aticker').tooltip({track: true}); // not working
 $(document).tooltip(); //not working ( i have to use selector and not document)
 $('.aticker').tooltip({tooltipClass:'rd'}); // not working


 <a href="#" class="aticker" id="answer2ticker" name="answer2ticker" style="width:42px; height:40px; display:inline-block; background-image:url('images/disabledtick.gif'); background-size:100%;" title="please login to choose the"></a>
```

not sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: post your html elements

Comment: Are you call tooltip method after DOM load?

Comment: Yes and I just edited the question with more details

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there was a confliction between bootstrap.js and jquery.js tooltip.
known issue

[Tooltip conflict with jQuery UI #6303](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6303)

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to comment because of a lack of reputation, so I will post this as an answer. I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJ6Aj/2/) based on your information. For me it seems to work perfectly well.

I used the links to the javascript files from your post and `$('.aticker').tooltip({track: true});` works.

Could you please provide further information such as any errors shown in the javascript console?